# Issues retrieving PubMed articles prior to 2019 using easyPubMed in R

Tags: r

I am facing a problem with my R script using the easyPubMed package to fetch articles from PubMed. My goal is to retrieve papers starting from 1999, but it seems that my script only returns results from 2019 onwards.

Here is the relevant part of my script:

```
term <- '(("1999/01/01"[Date - Publication] : "2023/11/12"[Date - Publication])) AND (Runs Of Homozygosity[Title/Abstract] OR homozygosity tracks[Title/Abstract])'
pmid_list <- easyPubMed::get_pubmed_ids(term)
pm_xml <- easyPubMed::fetch_pubmed_data(pmid_list)
pm_df <- easyPubMed::table_articles_byAuth(pubmed_data = pm_xml,
                                           included_authors = "first",
                                           getKeywords = TRUE, max_chars = 500)
new_PM_df$jabbrv <- substr(new_PM_df$jabbrv, 1, 20)
dat<-new_PM_df[c("pmid", "year", "lastname", "jabbrv")]
```

I have checked the syntax, and it seems correct. However, I am not getting results prior to 2019. I know that there are a lot of papers published before 2019. I wonder if there's something wrong with my query or if there are any limitations to retrieving older articles using easyPubMed.

```
table(dat$year)
2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 
  10   84  124  142  140
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The `fetch_pubmed_data` has a default `retmax` argument of 500 (you have a total of 500 in the batch returned). You can change this to alter the number of records returned at one time.